# Concurrently iterating through a map while inserting, in what way is it unsafe

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, visual-studio-2015, concurrency

Note: I know this is unsafe and undefined by the standard, looking to see if it's defined by my compiler, or if it's safe in practice.

I'm iterating over a map range in one thread, while potentially inserting in another thread

```
// thread 1:
for(auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it){
    // it's okay if "it" is out of order, repeats an element, or skips an element
    // it's bad  if "it" can skip map.end() or turn to mush (invalid iterator)
}

// thread 2:
map[Key(...)] = Type(...); // insertions are extremely rare but inevitable
```

This is unsafe, but um... how unsafe?  This map serves as an optimization hint to ease thread contention, so it itself can't contribute to that contention.  If the possible outcomes are only that the inserted element might be missed, or that it'll read elements out of order or twice, this is acceptable and won't break anything.

Would doing this turn iterators to soup or cause `map.end()` to be missed?  These are the only two outcomes that could ruin my life.

Comment: It's very unsafe - the map can get reallocated (i.e. you can get seg fault upon reading). You should guard insertion and access with a mutex.

Comment: @GeorgiGerganov - `std::map` iterators stay valid after insertions, the map's contents should be immobile in memory

Comment: But insertion is not atomic, so increasing iterator might then point on (invalid) `Node` in construction...

Comment: @Jarod42 - Ah, I didn't think of that, that alone would break things.  Thanks for the insight

Comment: Ok, seems my comment might not have been completely correct - no reallocations happen when inserting in map (thanks to @corolla comment below).

Comment: But reasoning about UB is senseless anyway, Compiler does magic optimization thanks to UB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, those outcomes could absolutely occur, *and worse*.

When you insert into a map, various internal operations occur. It's not just a `[]` and `=`: there is a whole algorithm going on underneath, potentially including rebalancing operations! (Refer to your old university notes on tree structure management for more information there.)

There are no guarantees whatsoever on what "observing" the map during the course of such an algorithm will result in, and the standard makes very clear that your program will have *undefined behaviour*. This is a two-fold problem: not only could you run into practical problems with the map, but your compiler knows that no well-defined program can get into this situation, and *can make optimisations based on the assumption that you didn't*. Now all hell breaks loose, [potentially in code not even related to your map accesses](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Modifying a map in one thread and reading from it in another, without synchronisation, is suicide, plain and simple. Don't try to outsmart the compiler/implementation: just code to contract.

Answer (score -2):

I'm semi-shooting from hip here, but let's say the underlying collection is implemented by allocating a fixed size upfront, then when required to grow it would potentially allocate e.g. 50% more to avoid repeated, small reallocations. The old collection entries would then be moved to the newly allocated memory and the old collection deallocated.

If you're iterating such a collection while inserting, the 'next' iterator could end up holding a pointer to a freed location.

Comment: Node-based collections such as maps and lists have different allocation semantics to block-based collections such as vectors.